# Google OAuth2 callback error

Tags: mongodb, express, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Very, very new to user authentication. Looking to allow users to register with Google.

Current status: I'm successfully making it to this step - 
(hiding my email(s))
[image: Google Account Selection]

But, when I click an account, I'm getting this error (500) (using longjohn for longer stack traces):

```
Error
    at /Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:95:21
    at passBackControl (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
---------------------------------------------
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:689:35)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:156:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:522:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:411:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:560:20)
---------------------------------------------
    at exports.OAuth2._executeRequest (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:147:11)
    at exports.OAuth2._request (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:120:8)
    at exports.OAuth2.get (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:227:8)
    at Strategy.userProfile (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/passport-google-oauth20/lib/strategy.js:84:16)
    at loadIt (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:345:17)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._loadUserProfile (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:360:25)
    at /Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:168:16
    at /Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:209:7
    at passBackControl (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:134:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:975:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
---------------------------------------------
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:689:35)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:156:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:522:21)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:411:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:560:20)
---------------------------------------------
    at exports.OAuth2._executeRequest (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:147:11)
    at exports.OAuth2._request (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:120:8)
    at exports.OAuth2.getOAuthAccessToken (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:190:8)
    at loaded (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:164:20)
    at NullStore.verify (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/state/null.js:9:3)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.authenticate (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:210:26)
    at attempt (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:348:16)
    at authenticate (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:349:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
---------------------------------------------
    at handleOperationCallback (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:454:24)
    at /Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:490:9
    at authenticateStragglers (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:429:16)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:463:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/squashtomato/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:319:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:560:20)
```

My code surrounding this functionality is:

```
// routes.js
router.get('/auth/google', authController.google);
router.get('/oauth2callback', authController.googleCallback
);

// passport.js
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:21015/auth/google/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      const user = new User();
      user.google.id = profile.id;
      user.google.token = accessToken;
      user.google.name = profile.displayName;
      user.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;
      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
));

// authController.js
const passport = require('passport');
exports.google = passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
});
exports.googleCallback = passport.authenticate('google', {
  failureRedirect: '/login', // if fail, where to go
  failureFlash: 'Failed Login!', // if fail, what to flash
  successRedirect: '/', // if success, where to go
  successFlash: 'You are now logged in!' // if success, what to flash
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can not use an IP address as and end-point, so try to change your callback-url to : `http://localhost:21015/oauth2callback`

Comment: If that's what it is, I'm going to cry! Will let you know in a bit!

Comment: Still failing... It never returns back to my site when I give my application permissions via google. It redirects to the callbackURL I have set, but fails to connect?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have enabled Google+ API in https://console.cloud.google.com. 
To use google Auth you have to enable the API in google console. A very common mistake is when you go to Google Developer Console to enable an API for your project, first time for a project it asks you to create Credentials. The problem is after you create credentials the google+ API (or any other APIs) won't be enabled automatically and you should enable it from your project page in google developer console.
STEPS:

1. Go to [Google Console](https://console.cloud.google.com)
2. Select your project from the top nav (if you didn't yet)
3. Click on Enable APIS and Services
4. In the search box search for Google Plus
5. Select the first result , Google+ API
6. Click Enable

If you don't see the Enable button and see the 'Create Credentials' button,it means you didn't create credentials yet and follow the instructions on the page to create one. Don't forget to enable API after creating credentials.

For more information you can read this instruction from google [Enable and disable APIs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158841?hl=en)

Besides what mentioned above, you don't need to use an absolute URL for your callback and simply you can use a relative one like: `/auth/google/callback`

```js
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CONSUMER_KEY,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      const user = new User();
      user.google.id = profile.id;
      user.google.token = accessToken;
      user.google.name = profile.displayName;
      user.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;
      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
));
```